# Conversion of public key parameters from Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA into JWK failed

Tags: perl, openssl, rsa, jwk

I was creating a mock server for OAuth2 and I was stuck on during the generation of a JWK token, more specifically, I failed to understand how to convert the `e` and `n` parameters

I have this code:

```perl
use strict;
use v5.26.0;
use Data::Dumper;              # or DDP if have i t installed!
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt decode_jwt);
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum;    # needs to be installed in order to run $rsa_pub->get_key_parameters();
use MIME::Base64;

# don't worry, this is just a test/mock server with 'random' generated RSA pair
my $rsa_pvt = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key(
    '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
);

my $rsa_pub = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key(
    '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA0LdLaW9i0NUVwV1+ZSnwwYebLliFLCEQjzsklGww0fYa0VWMkEl/
WD1mam/idqqAadkgMKzZY4JWx824rRpHOosTJbOMHKa1cRA933yv8Ywzahmxih9J
x/QjK2VHSlxTRq2cKN/E9S2VN64PBlBc2LsoAzM9M4r9X90KJFi3+VazjDZ+9iWA
5UCqrWcGrEy21ZVLF27Dm03STIewtV9goBn/7Gd5sMfDfnvMLKSK5ZRbGigtfkjS
91qZUiHjU+WXJrMS2mTr/W9fmAJ7R9jQ09wpJVqP+UOnFjL/0mesAQ5H4FTtRoXh
YiKF3zqckRkAwRuP3sv2nCGA8MoiZR5rFwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'
);

my ($n, $e, @o) = $rsa_pub->get_key_parameters();


# I think something is wrong in this conversion
$n = encode_base64($n->to_bin(), '');
$e = encode_base64($e->to_bin(), '');

my $kids = {
    "keys" => [
        {
            "kty" => "RSA",
            "kid" => "rsa1",
            "alg" => "RS256",
            "use" => "sig",
            "n"   => $n,
            "e"   => $e
        }
    ]
};
say "Keys parameters";
say Dumper($kids);

my $encoded = encode_jwt(
    payload       => {a => 'b'},
    alg           => 'RS256',
    key           => $rsa_pvt,
    extra_headers => {'kid' => 'rsa1'},
);

say "Generated JWT: $encoded";

my $decoded_with_pub = decode_jwt(
    token => $encoded,
    key   => $rsa_pub,
);

say "Decoded with pub certificate";
say Dumper($decoded_with_pub);


say "Trying to decode with certificate from parameters";

# do not returns,
# Use of uninitialized value in unpack at ~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Crypt/PK/RSA.pm line 102.
my $decoded_with_kid = decode_jwt(
    token    => $encoded,
    kid_keys => $kids,
);
```

The Crypt::JWT is working when I test with the production keys `https://sso.staging.acesso.gov.br/jwk`

The `e` parameter AQAB (same recommended exponent of 65537) is matching, so I don't know how else I should convert the `n` from BigInt into Base64 any different than the way I did

SEO:

Use of uninitialized value in unpack at ~/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Crypt/PK/RSA.pm line 102.

Answer (score 2):

So, 5 months in, I was no long needing this, but I just sent this same question to chat GPT 4 and... it found the error!

Just replace

```
$n = encode_base64($n->to_bin(), '');
$e = encode_base64($e->to_bin(), '');
```

with

```
$n = encode_base64url($n->to_bin());
$e = encode_base64url($e->to_bin());
```

and adjust MIME::Base64 use:

`use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64url);`

The issue that I was using encode_base64 instead of encode_base64url for encoding the 'n' and 'e' parameters of the RSA key. This caused an error in the JWT decoding process, as JWK requires these parameters to be in base64url format according to the RFC 7518 standard. By making these adjustments, the error was resolved, and the decoding with the kid_keys parameter worked as expected.